execution of try and exception in output
I'm having a problem with a program where it runs the exception along with the try command and I don't know what to do since it prints the conversion and the error message.
def main():
    print('What would you like to convert?')
    print('1. Miles to Kilometers')
    print('2. Fahrenheit to Celcius')
    print('3. Gallons to Liters')
    print('4. Pounds to Kilograms')
    print('5. Inches to Centimeters')
    try:
        option = int(input('Menu Option:'))
        if option == 1:
            Inptmiles = float(input('Enter number of miles to convert:'))
            milestokm(Inptmiles)
            usercontinue()
        if option == 2:
            InptFrnht = float(input('Enter degrees that you would like to convert:'))
            FrnhttoClcs(InptFrnht)
            usercontinue()
        if option == 3:
            InptGllns = float(input('Enter number of Gallons you would like to convert:'))
            GllnstoLtrs(InptGlls)
            usercontinue()
        if option == 4:
            InptLbs = float(input('Enter number of pounds you would like to convert:'))
            LbstoKgs(InptLbs)
            usercontinue()
        if option == 5:
            InptInches = float(input('Enter number of Inches you would like to convert:'))
            InchestoCm(InptInches)
            usercontinue()
    except:
        print('Sorry there was an error with your input')
def milestokm(miles):
    convkm = miles * 1.6
    print(f'{miles} Miles is equal to {convkm:.2f} Kilometers')
def FrnhttoClcs(Fahrenheit):
    convClcs = (Fahrenheit - 32) * 5/9
    print(f'{Fahrenheit} Degrees Fahrenheit is equal to {convClcs:.2f} Degrees Celcius')
def GllnstoLtrs(Gallons):
    convLtrs = Gallons * 3.9
    print(f'{Gallons} Gallons is equal to {convLtrs:.2f} Liters')
def LbstoKgs(Pounds):
    convKgs = Pounds * 0.45
    print(f'{Pounds} Pounds is equal to {convKgs:.2f} Kilograms')
def InchestoCm(Inches):
    convCm = Inches * 2.54
    print(f'{Inches} Inches is equal to {convCm:.2f} Centimeters')
    
main()

I tried moving the exception down past the define commands that used the stored variables but it came back as an error.

You should always include an exit(0) condition for the user, too!

This is exactly why you should never just use try ... except ... without specifying a specific exception. If you re-raise the exception, you'll find that the issue is a missing definition:
except Exception as e:
    print('Sorry there was an error with your input')
    raise e

Output will be something like:
...
Sorry there was an error with your input
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path>\main.py", line 60, in <module>
    main()
  File "<path>\main.py", line 32, in main
    raise(e)
  File "<path>\main.py", line 13, in main
    usercontinue()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'usercontinue' is not defined

So, instead only catch the exception you expect and allow others to pass, after you fix the issue:
except ValueError:
    print('Sorry there was an error with your input')

...

def usercontinue():
    # whatever you planned here
    pass


I think you might have said the opposite of what you wanted in your first sentence.

ftfy. I too hope the author meant that.

Totally, complete typo, thanks for the correction

Thank you, I'm still learning this so I didn't really understand to specify the exception.

An error is raised because name 'usercontinue' is not defined.
To find the error, I used this snippet of code:
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

